# How do you reorder picklist items in ActiveAdmin filters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a filter for schedule name in ActiveAdmin that has about 90 options in the pull down menu. It is difficult to find the one you want so reordering the picklist items by name in ascending order would make finding the right one easier.

I don't want to change the sort order for the entire page, just the items in the picklist for the filter.

Tried adding a collection to sort them but it is not working.

```ruby
    filter :schedule, :collection => Schedule.order("name ASC").all
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the call to `.all`? The default scope for `Schedule` should be all

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
filter :schedule, as: :select, :collection -> { Schedule.pluck(:name, :id).sort }
```